# Setup global environnement variables for all Docker containers

Tags: docker, systemd

Is it possible to set env. variables for all futur Docker containers?

This will be helpful to setup http proxy for a particular host without changing Docker image file or the way you run the container (so same Docker container can run fine on different "context").

Maybe via `/etc/default/docker`?

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose uses variable substitution so you can use host variables in a docker-compose file:

If your bash session has a variable called `EXTERNAL_PORT` defined.

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "${EXTERNAL_PORT}:5000"
```

Check: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Also in case of a proxy I'm guessing that using `HTTP_PROXY` should redirect the traffic by default if is defined in the current shell session.

```
export http_proxy=http://10.203.0.1:5187/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Something like that should redirect all http traffic, you can set it from `.bashrc`. Never tested with docker let me know if it works.

Comment: I am not talking about docker-compose, sorry.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux Then you should try `HTTP_PROXY` is not related to docker or docker-compose for configuring a proxy, it's just a linux env variable. There's also a windows counterpart for it. I would create a custom user for running the images with all the env vars configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using docker-compose as Marcs said, then no.

Dockerfiles create binaries. Anything not specified in the dockerfile (or docker-compose yaml or the `docker build`) will not make its way into the container. This is for many security reasons as well as just general best practices as people could cause these containers to be dependent on the host itself. Either use docker-compose to do your building or look into making changes to the host itself that would affect that layer of the docker container such as  a system-wide proxy that affects the 172 subnet

Comment: Dockerfile create image, that you run via ``docker run`` no ? I would like pass ``docker run -e K1=V1 ...`` automatically. So developers don't care about proxy.